# Type mismatch required: Option[Any] => Option[Nothing]

Tags: scala, typeerror, scala-option

How can I fix this type error?

```
object Test extends App {
  def printOption[A](a: Option[A]): Option[A] = { println(a getOrElse("none")); a }

  def printHashCodeAndMap[A, B](fn: Option[A] => Option[B], list: List[Option[A]]): List[Option[B]] = {
    for (elem <- list) yield fn(elem.map{a => println(a.hashCode()); a})
  }

  val optListA = List(Some("aa"), None, Some(5))

  val optListB = printHashCodeAndMap(printOption, optListA)
  for (x <- optListB) printOption(x)
}
```

The error I get is:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Option[Nothing] => Option[Nothing]
required: Option[Any] => Option[Nothing]
val optListB = printHashCodeAndMap(printOption, optListA)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with how scala infers type parameters. Types information flows from left to right across parameter groups but not within the same parameter group.

What that means is: the type parameter of `printOption`, `A` can be inferred only if `A` has been bound to a real type in a parameter group that precedes it's occurrence. In your `printHashCodeAndMap`, this is not the case. So, there are two ways to get this to work.

i. You can forsake the type inference and explicitly specify the types of `fn` by passing it `printOption[Any]`. Or you could just specify the type parameters of `printHashCodeAndMap` when you call it (i.e. `printHashCodeAndMap[Any, Any](printOption, optListA)`)

ii. If you wanted to use scala's type inferrence, you'd want the type information for `A` to come from `optListA` which is of type `List[Option[Any]]`. To make that happen the parameter `list` has to be in a parameter group that precedes `fn`. Like this:

```
def printHashCodeAndMap[A, B](list: List[Option[A]])(fn: Option[A] => Option[B]): List[Option[B]] = { ... }
```

Then you will be able to call it like this:

```
printHashCodeAndMap(optListA)(printOption)
```

Comment: This was really helpful info. Any idea why type inference does not work left-to-right within the same parameter group?

Comment: I don't think I really completely understand the reasons behind it. But I think [this blog post](http://pchiusano.blogspot.com/2011/05/making-most-of-scalas-extremely-limited.html) and the comments on it point in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
val optListB = printHashCodeAndMap(printOption[Any], optListA)
```

Comment: Thanks. This means that we cannot pass a generic function to a higher-order function? Still, I expected that it would default to printOption[Any], not to printOption[Nothing]...

Comment: `Nothing` is a subclass in the very bottom of Scala hierarchy. Elements of argument list to a method, are in a `[-]` variance position by default, so a function which does not make its input type explicitly set gets `Nothing` in the end.

Comment: This can be explained clearer by `Liskov` substitution principle. If `function<Any>` is the subclass of `function<A>`, then each and every time you use `function<A>` - you could use a `function<Any>` instead, but its clearly not true, - because `A` can be different, and you could expect `AnyVal`-s in your `function[A <: AnyVal]`, for example